# Excel Rate Function in JavaScript - FormulaJS error

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to get the same values as Excel / Google Sheets **RATE** function using JavaScript. I am using the library [Formulajs](https://formulajs.info/) to try and achieve this.

When I try to find rate for NPER 360 | PMT: 599.55 | PV: 100,000 the result is 0.004999993193119239. When I multiply this by 12 (months) and 100 (convert to percentage), I am getting the right result 6% (5.99999183174).

The problem starts when I try to find rate for NPER 360 | PMT: 12200 | PV: 100,000 with

`RATE(360, -12200, 100000, 0, 0, 0.1)`

the result is -1.013705559223954. When I multiply this by 12 (months) and 100 (convert to percent) I get a ridiculous -1216.44667107, but trying the same on Google sheets gives me **146.40**

I don't know if I am using these functions right, or I am missing some major part of the calculation. Am I doing something wrong here? Is there any library that can give me the RATE function as close to excel as possible?

Comment: formulajs site does not have a detailed documentation on the exact arguments for the `RATE` function. it is possible different arguments have to be used to get correct result

Comment: the implementation and argument meaning of `RATE` function is [here](https://github.com/handsontable/formula.js/blob/develop/lib/financial.js#L783)

Comment: also isnt `RATE(360, -12200, 100000, 0, 0, 0.1)` supposed to be `RATE(360,, 12200, 100000, 0, 0, 0.1)` ?

Comment: The rate is supposed to be RATE(360, -12200, 100000, 0, 0, 0.1), the minus sign is there because it is a payment.

I also checked their git repository and separately tested their RATE function, but I still keep getting the error in calculation. It is way off from excel result.

Comment: I think that the question is too broad and it could be better to post one question for each app.